Visual intuition for normal subgroups
I've read this discussion on Intuition behind normal subgroups, but I'm still unable to create a mental picture of what is going on behind the scenes. I'm trying to build an alternative visualization.
For a finite group $G$, a subgroup $H \subset G$ is said normal if satisfies:
$$
gH = Hg, \forall g \in G
\tag{1}
$$
My goal with this question is to come up with a visual interpretation for (1). Let's consider two arbitrary cosets for $G$, $Hg^{-1}, rH$.  The cosets are shown below, including their respective representatives $w$ and $z$.

I'm guessing that if we have (the red arrows in the figure):
$$
\begin{align}
w^{-1} g^{-1} \in H \\
z r^{-1} \in H
\end{align}
\tag{2}
$$
Then, we can build the following path (shown in blue in the figure):
$$
gH rH = w^{-1}z = h_{2} g h_{4}r
\tag{3}
$$
My intuition says that (2) and (3) should be enough to prove (1), but I'm stuck at this moment. This strategy makes any sense at all?

Edit
I ended up reading this beautiful post with some motivation behind normal subgroups. After reading it and with the comments of @JohnDouma, I came up with another view of the problem.
I understood the main idea as follows. Let $gH$ be an arbitrary coset whose representative is $[g]$. For the set of representatives form a group we need:
$$
[g] \circ [g^{-1}] = [e]
\tag{4}
$$
Eq. (4) implies that for any two representatives in $\{ [g], [g^{-1}], [e]\}$ the third is determined.
Note that given $gh_{1} \in gH$, and $h_{2} \in H$, even if $H$ is not normal, we have the following condition (illustrated on the left of the figure below):
$$
gh_{1} \circ \underbrace{ (h_{1}^{-1} g^{-1} h _{2}) }_{ r } = h_{2}
$$

Now, if $H$ is normal, Eq. (4) implies that for any representative in $[g]$ and $[e]$ we can still create another path which coincides with $r$, which is also shown on the left of the above figure.
In particular, we can think that the simplest description for $r$ will appear when the representative of $[g]$ is $gh_{1}$ and the representative of $[e]$ is $h_{2}$. This implies that $r \in [g^{-1}]$, say $r = h_{3}g^{-1}$, and:
$$
\begin{align}
g h_{1} \circ h_{3} g^{-1} = h_{2} \implies \\
g h_{4} = h_{2} g
\end{align}
\tag{5}
$$
which implies (1).
To see more clearly why the elements of $g$ are said to commute with $H$, we can replace $r$ in the left figure by $h_{3}g^{-1}$. The new obtained figure is shown below:

Then, after a translation by $h_{3}$, we find that there are two paths that connect the green points: the red and blue, which implies:
$$
\begin{align}
h_{3}^{-1} \circ h_{i} \circ (h_{k}g^{-1}) = g^{-1} \circ h_{j}^{-1} \implies
h_{l} g^{-1} = g^{-1}h_{m}
\end{align}
\tag{6}
$$

Do you understand the concept of a quotient group? A normal subgroup acts like the identity element in a quotient group. The identity of any group commutes with all elements of the group, which is why $gH=Hg$. The identity is also  thought of as being the value $1$, which is why we call it a normal subgroup: it is normalized. It turns out, as in many of the answers in your link, that normal subgroups are equivalent to kernels of group homomorphisms.

Could you please tell where the image is taken from?

@SohamSaha I did myself

That’s wonderful, what software are you using?

@JohnDouma I'm aware of the concept of quotient group, but it's not obvious that Eq. (1) implies that the cosets form a group. I would like to see the simplest visual explanation for that.

@SohamSaha Inkscape with latex shortcuts, see more on https://castel.dev/post/lecture-notes-2/

Would an algebraic explanation of why $gH=Hg$ allows us to define multiplication that satisfies the group axioms suffice?

@JohnDouma It would convince me but it wouldn't entry my heart. In fact, there are plenty of them in the question that I cited.

@JohnDouma I did an update, let me know what you think.

I don't know what you mean by subtraction but saying that $gh_1g^{-1}h_2=e$ is incorrect. The equivalence class $\lvert e\rvert$ is the normal subgroup $H$ so we are trying to show that $gh_1g^{-1}h_2\in H$. To translate $gh_1g^{-1}h2$ to $gg^{-1}h$, we require that $gH=Hg$.  Essentially $gh_1g^{-1}h_2=g(h_1g^{-1})h_2$ and, since $g^{-1}H=Hg^{-1}$, we can find $h_3$ such that $h_1g^{-1}=g^{-1}h_3$. This gives $gg^{-1}h_3h_2=h_3h_2\in H$.

@JohnDouma you are right. I did another update with your comment in mind. Hopefully I have the right picture now. Let me know.

As someone who spent a few years trying to understand this part of algebra more visually I have two comments:

Equation (1) tells you nothing about the internal structure of $H$ -- if you use the phrase "element of $H$" in setting up or describing your picture, you are not capturing the content of equation (1).

Equation (1) does tell you about the partitioning of $G$ by cosets of $H$ -- so you should be thinking of $G$ partitioned into pieces congruent to $H$ in two different ways (as left cosets and as right cosets), with a miraculous two-part coincidence:

The two partitions are into the same subsets.
Each element of $g$ takes $H$ to the same left and right coset.

That is, generically, the subsets of $G$ that are left cosets of $H$ need not be the same as the subsets of $G$ that are right cosets of $H$.  That they are the same subsets is a coincidence of note.  Also, we can label each left coset by the element of $G$ such that $gH$ is that coset.  And we can label the right cosets the same way.  With the coincidence of partitions of $G$, each subset is labelled with two collections of elements of $g$.  The second coincidence is that the two collections are equal in every subset.


The picture I ended up with (to capture the factorization by normal subgroups) was to have $H$ be a vertical column in a 3-dimensional array (usually on the closest corner so it is easy to see), each other column is a coset of $H$ (and we don't have to specify whether the columns are left cosets or right cosets, because "yes"), and the slices perpendicular to $H$ are cosets of $G/H$.  The slice containing $e$ is a set of representatives of $G/H$ in $G$.  The other slices are cosets of $G/H$, but the second coincidence fails: which elements of $H$ take the $e$-slice to that slice on the left and on the right need not be the same.  (If the cosets of $G/H$ do have the second coincidence, then $G$ is the direct product of $H$ and $G/H$.  There are many examples of groups having normal subgroups for which this second coincidence does not occur.)

Here, the elements of $G$ in a coset of $H$ are the same color.  This is a busy image, and I think a better artist could pick colors to help the eye more than I did.  The $eH$ and $He$ coset are of course the elements of $H$.  For any coset of $H$, say $g_1 H$, $g_1$ is in $g_1 H$ because $g_1 e = g_1$.  Likewise, every element of that coset takes $H$ to that coset.  One of the normalcy coincidences can be explained on this diagram: $g_1 H$ ca be as shown, but $H g_1$ can lie at a slope through $g_1$, say $(1,0,1)$; then $g_1 H \neq H g_1$ (and "projection along $H$" has a left version and a right version that produce different partitions of $G$, so $H$ isn't normal).  Then the process of quotienting by $H$ crushes everything onto the $xy$-plane -- each coset of $H$ crushes to one element of $G/H$ -- we've picked a set of representatives, one from each coset, the ones that happen to be in the $e$-plane perpendicular to $H$.  (Note that this choice is "generic": you can permute the elemets of $G$ in any coset of $H$ and still get the same picture, with the option to have a different representative of the coset.)  Finally, if $H$ and/or $G$ are big, one should allow the diagram to continue off as much as needed in the $x$-, $y$-, and/or $z$-directions.
In reality, neither $H$ nor $G/H$ should really be considered one-dimensional or two-dimensional, since either could decompose into various kinds of products of their various normal subgroups.  (See group extension, where a 2-dimensional version of the above diagram appears.  Don't worry about the details of short exact sequences.  That one says that $N$ is a subgroup of $G$ and $G/N$ is a group, so $N$ is a normal (otherwise the left and right cosets don't mesh to let $G/N$ as a set form a group) factor of $G$.)
Also, you will eventually want to understand "characteristic", a sort of "super-normal".  You will get a lot farther with visual understanding if you re-write equation (1) as
$$  gHg^{-1} = H  \text{.}  $$
capturing a different aspect of normalcy.  The object on the left is the conjugate of $H$ by $g$.  These provide a different partitioning of $G$ and both normalcy and charistic-ness are easier to compare and contrast in terms of this partitioning.

Thanks for the detailed answer! Could you please provide a simple image describing your three-dimensional array? I was trying to build one based on your description, but I'm facing some doubts.

Added an image and some discussion of the image.

Thanks! In the meantime, I have done more research on the subject and I've wrote an update. Let me know what you think.
